# How to correctly handle a many to many relationship in OOP?

Tags: java, oop, dictionary

I'm building a Java application for a school project which requires some data to have a many to many relationship. Basically I currently have a class called 'Skill' which contains data such as a brief description of the skill.

```
public class Skill 
{
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private int maxLevel;

    public int getMaxLevel()
    {
        return maxLevel;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

}
```

The reason I made this a class is so that skills can be created and removed within the GUI without using any Runtime class editing. Then there is a student class. Each student will have all the skills mapped to an integer value that represents their level in this skill.

```
public class Student
{
    private String studentName;
    private HashMap<Skill, Integer> skillMap;

    public void levelUp(Skill skillToLevel)
    {
        int oldValue = skillMap.get(skillToLevel);
        skillMap.remove(skillToLevel);
        skillMap.put(skillToLevel, ++oldValue);
    }

}
```

Both classes are Serializable and are Loaded into the program at the start and saved again at the end. Basically, I'm wondering if this is the best way of doing this, To me it seems messy and somewhat sloppy. I've been researching into some Design Patterns recently but again, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please learn to stop writing and saying "basically".  It's a filler word, a high tech "um".

Comment: "To me it seems messy and somewhat sloppy." - why?  What's so sloppy?  Implement it, see if works.  Change if it doesn't.

Comment: Got it, Thanks for the advice. This is what I already have implemented, It works sure, however, I just thought it seemed amateurish. Fair enough though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the right way of doing things when it comes to manyToMany relationships is creating an association class, in this case you may create a third class student_skill in which you may put the methods and attributes concerning both students and their skills.
I also think that you should pick up the habit of using a unique ID in your classes, using a name as an ID is not optimal in any way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, In my actual class I am using a unique user ID because it's what I use for the filename of the Student's data. As for the association class, This was my first consideration before the HashMap, however, it quickly became confusing to me. In my old version, A student would have a "Student_Skill" Array, and the "Student_Skill" class would hold the integer value of their level in that skill. Was this the correct way of doing it? Or was my method the reason it seemed confusing? Thanks again though!

Comment: Both student and skill should have a "student_skill" array,  and in the student_skill class you should add the IDs of both the student and the skill concerned.